# Использование указателя на указатель

Tags: c++

Как произвести, используя указатель на указатель, проверку на нуль при делении?

Comment: Проверить, не ссылается ли указатель на нулевой указатель или деление на нуль?

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Делении чего на что, и при чем тут указатели?

Answer (score 5):

Примерно так

```
int x = 1;
int *y = &x;
int **z = &y;

if (**z != 0)
    **z = 1 / **z;
```

`z` - это указатель на `y`, `y` - это указатель на `x`, а `x` - это то целое, которое проверяется на ноль перед делением. Операции над `**z` равноценны операциям над `x.`

Comment: Лучше:
<pre>int x = 1;
int \*y = &x;
int \*\*z = &y;
...
if (z != NULL)
  if (\*z != NULL) //  иначе разыменовываем NULL-указатель и приехали!
  //Ну, или сравнение с null_ptr - что там есть в ЯП.
    if (*\*z != 0)
      \*\*z = 1 / \*\*z;</pre>

Answer (score 2):

```
try 
{
     //Делаешь что надо
} 
catch(Exception &e)
{
     // Здесь что надо сделать если неполучилось
}
```